# Why does a STORAGEADD op (SSTORE) add 80 bytes to state rather than 32?

Tags: gas, storage, fees, opcode, state

According to [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15wghZr-Z6sRSMdmRmhls9dVXTOpxKy8Y64oy9MvDZEQ/edit#gid=0) that Vitalik has referenced before, stating that it's what they used to determine gas fees for each opcode, a STORAGEADD opcode (presumably renamed to SSTORE) is considered to add 80 bytes to state. Why 80 as opposed to 32, when the storage slot is only 32 bytes?